# how to effect all application ui when my android application localization language is changed through dynamically?

Tags: android

I am implementing my android application in this when i click anyone of my 6 languages list fragment then i need to change the all application ui(buttons names, Textview,..) into my selected language. I am not understanding how to do this, so could you please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually had a similar problem. Check out this example from the Android Developer site: [How to Create Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Example:

Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose also that you want to localize all the text in your application to French, and most of the text in your application (everything except the application's title) to Japanese. In this case, you could create three alternative **strings.xml** files, each stored in a locale-specific resource directory:

**res/values/strings.xml**
Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses, including text for a string named title.
**res/values-fr/strings.xml**
Contain French text for all the strings, including title.

**res/values-ja/strings.xml**
Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.
If your Java code refers to R.string.title, here is what will happen at runtime:

If the device is set to French, Android will load title from the **res/values-fr/strings.xml** file.
Notice that if the device is set to Japanese, Android will look for title in the **res/values-ja/strings.xml** file. But because no such string is included in that file, Android will fall back to the default, and will load title in English from the **res/values/strings.xml file**.

Comment: i did it's working to the selected language but my intention is without starting the activity i need to apply the selected language to all fragments.(for Example in my list fragment when i clicked the preferred language then the left side of the list items also need to change into my preferred language).